# indexing in elasticsearch using spark in standalone mode

Tags: java, elasticsearch, apache-spark

I want to index in elasticsearch from spark. It throws following exception...

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, localhost): java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
>       at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1967)
>       at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.discoverNodes(RestClient.java:110)
>       at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.InitializationUtils.discoverNodesIfNeeded(InitializationUtils.java:58)
>       at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestService.createWriter(RestService.java:372)
>       at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsRDDWriter.write(EsRDDWriter.scala:40)
>       at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsSpark$$anonfun$saveToEs$1.apply(EsSpark.scala:67)
>       at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsSpark$$anonfun$saveToEs$1.apply(EsSpark.scala:67)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
>       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Driver stacktrace:
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1283)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1271)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1270)
>       at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>       at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1270)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
>       at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1496)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1458)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1447)
>       at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:567)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1822)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1835)
>       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1912)
>       at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsSpark$.saveToEs(EsSpark.scala:67)
>       at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsSpark$.saveToEs(EsSpark.scala:52)
>       at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.api.java.JavaEsSpark$.saveToEs(JavaEsSpark.scala:54)
>       at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.api.java.JavaEsSpark.saveToEs(JavaEsSpark.scala)
>       at com.tgt.search.metrics.es.bulk.Sparkimporter.main(Sparkimporter.java:88)
>   Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
>       at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1967)
>       at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestClient.discoverNodes(RestClient.java:110)
>       at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.InitializationUtils.discoverNodesIfNeeded(InitializationUtils.java:58)
>       at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestService.createWriter(RestService.java:372)
>       at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsRDDWriter.write(EsRDDWriter.scala:40)
>       at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsSpark$$anonfun$saveToEs$1.apply(EsSpark.scala:67)
>       at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsSpark$$anonfun$saveToEs$1.apply(EsSpark.scala:67)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
>       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

This is my code...

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local")
            .setAppName("Indexer").set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "2g");
    conf.set("es.index.auto.create", "true");
    conf.set("es.nodes", "localhost");
    conf.set("es.port", "9200");
    conf.set("es.write.operation", "index");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    Map<String, ?> numbers = ImmutableMap.of("one", 1, "two", 2);
    Map<String, ?> airports = ImmutableMap.of("OTP", "Otopeni", "SFO", "San Fran");

    JavaRDD<Map<String, ?>> javaRDD = jsc.parallelize(ImmutableList.of(doc1, doc2));
    JavaEsSpark.saveToEs(javaRDD, "spark/docs");
```

I tried to write the file in local which is working fine.... it might be a problem in configuration.

These are the dependencies in my pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId> <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId> 
        <version>2.6.4</version> </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-spark_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1):

The relevant lines in your stacktrace are:

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range:
>   -1 at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1967) at ...

This error is not from your code. It is caused by the incompatibility between the elasticsearch version and the elasticsearch-hadoop adapter that you are using. The elasticsearch-hadoop adapters with versions 2.0.x and 2.1.x work with elasticsearch 1.x only. I faced the same error with elasticsearch 2.1.1, and had to downgrade my elasticsearch version to 1.4.4. And the error disappeared.

See the answer by costin [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop/issues/610)